# use awk and zsh to configure program reading data from ~/.netrc file

Tags: awk, zsh

let's say I have in `~/.netrc` few entries like this:

```
machine    *******************
login      *******
password   **********

machine    *********************
login      *****************
password   **********
```

with this script I can configure `git ftp` by populating first machine block
from above:

```
print "$(awk '/machine/ { skip = !skip; }; skip { print $1" "$2 }' ~/.netrc)" | while read k v
do
    case $k in
        machine )
            print git.config ftp.url $v
            ;;
        login )
            print git.config ftp.user $v
            ;;
        password )
            print git.config ftp.password $v
    esac
done
```

however I would like to be able, for flexibility reasons, to give this script an argument being machine
name, so that only that block is used from above;

how to instruct `awk` to use that argument when reading `~/.netrc` and stop on the
next machine instance?

EDIT: now I realised that I have even one more flaw in the code as it is, and
that is: because of a skip switch, every 2nd machine block will be read, and I
want one and only one to be used, where machine name matches user provided
argument.

Comment: You don't need to capture `awk`'s output just to print it back to standard output: `awk '...' | while ...` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

if the machine name is in the masked field 2 you can do this

```
awk -v RS= -v name="****etc" '$1=="machine" && $2==name {...`
```

or hardcode the name in the awk script.  By setting awk to paragraph mode you can group the lines into one logical record separated by empty lines.

Comment: can't do like that, because then only that machine line would be read, and not the other two.. login and password